# Python Pandas : Highlight min values except less 0

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and I would like to highlight the max and min values. But excluding the "0" for highlighting the minimum

So basically starting the min highlight from > 0

This is what I have so far:

```
cols_to_highlight = allContainer_circle_fillstate.columns[4:]
allContainer_circle_fillstate = allContainer_circle_fillstate.style.highlight_max(subset=cols_to_highlight, color='red', axis=0)\
                                    .highlight_min(subset=cols_to_highlight, color='lightgreen', axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for replace values less like `0` to missing values:

```
np.random.seed(123)

f = lambda x: f'col{x+1}'
allContainer_circle_fillstate=pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([1, 7, 0, 2], 
                                                           size=(5,10))).rename(columns=f)
print (allContainer_circle_fillstate)

   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7  col8  col9  col10
0     0     7     0     0     1     0     0     7     2      0
1     2     7     0     7     1     7     0     2     7      1
2     0     1     2     7     2     0     7     1     1      1
3     1     7     2     2     0     1     2     0     1      2
4     1     7     1     2     7     2     1     1     1      0

cols_to_highlight = allContainer_circle_fillstate.columns[4:] 

def highlight_max(s, props=''):
    return np.where((s == np.nanmax(s.values)), props, '')

def highlight_min(s, props=''):
    return np.where((s == np.nanmin(np.where(s > 0, s.values, np.nan))), props, '')

(allContainer_circle_fillstate.style.apply(highlight_max, subset=cols_to_highlight, props='color:red', axis=0)
                                    .apply(highlight_min, subset=cols_to_highlight, props='color:lightgreen', axis=0))
```

---

[image: pic]